# Fill a form with a form

Tags: php, forms, function

I am developing in php, and I need to fill out a form with the fields completed from a first form (with others in addition).

How can I do this? Or how can I call a function in PHP as a form action?

Thanks

```
$param['vads_currency']  = "978"; //EUR
$param['vads_ctx_mode']  = "TEST"; 
$param['vads_page_action']  = "PAYMENT";
$param['vads_action_mode']  = "INTERACTIVE";
$param['vads_payment_config']= "SINGLE";
$param['vads_version']   = "V2";
$param['vads_capture_delay'] = "0";
$param['vads_validation_mode'] = "1";
$param['vads_trans_date']= gmdate ("YmdHis");
$param['vads_trans_id']= gmdate ("His");
$param['vads_order_id']= '';
$param['vads_return_mode'] = "POST";


print_r ($param);
 
// Signature générée 
ksort($param); // Tri des champs par ordre alphabétique
$contenu_signature = ""; 
foreach ($param as $nom => $valeur) 
{ //Récupération des champs vads_
  if(substr($nom,0,5) == 'vads_') 
  { 
    //Concaténation avec le séparateur "+
    $contenu_signature .= $valeur."+"; 
  } 
}
$contenu_signature .= $key;  // Ajout de la clé en fin de chaine
echo $contenu_signature;
$param['signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $contenu_signature, $key, true));// //Encodage base64 de la chaine chiffrée avec l'algorithme HMAC-SHA-256



    




?> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Formulaire Paiement</title> 
</head> 
<body>

<form method="POST" action=""> 
<input type="text" placeholder="nom" name="nom"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="prenom" name="nom"/>
<input type="number" placeholder="montant" name="montant"/>

<input type="submit" name="remplir" value="Continuer" /> 


</form>

    <?php
    ?>
<form method="POST" action="https://paiement.systempay.fr/vads-payment/"> 


    <!-- URLpage de paiement -->
<?php 
foreach($param as $nom => $valeur) 
{ 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $nom. '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($valeur , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '" />'; 
  
} 
?> 
<input type="submit" name="payer" value="Payer" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

So, the first form is the one that contains the fields whose data I have to send back to the second form, which generates itself

Comment: do you have some code to show ?

Comment: Have I understood correctly that you have saved values from an initial form submit, which you then later want to output as editable data to the user? Usually this is done by saving the data to a database, and then reading it back, outputting the data as form field values. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i've uptaded guys, and i can't do that with a database because it's for a wordpress site... and i only need that to complete a payment system so i want to do that without sending data to a db.

Comment: Does both forms are visible to the user or the first one need to be submitted in order to fill the second? If you want to fill it dynamically (on key up) the only way i can think of is by using `javascript`.